# How to stop getting the previous value when changing the option in select where i am using live change jquery function

Tags: jquery

i am using a table where the select option is populated according to no of rows present in table. here i am using live change function in jquery to track the live change and i am storing in variable but when click next option it return the previous value.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.sel').live('change',function(event)
    {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $(".save").click(function()
        {

            console.log(selected);
            if(selected == 'NULL')
            {
                alert("Select An Option");
            }
            if(selected == 'taking')
            {
                alert("taking");
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems to me that the new value for selected is out of scope when the click function is called.

Comment: FYI, `.live()` is deprecated, and removed in jQuery 1.9. You should convert to `.on()`.

Comment: but the value is storing in the selected variable and when click a button and after i change a select option the previous value is displayed in console along with newly stored value @puelo

Comment: The problem is that you're binding multiple click handlers. Every time you change `.live`, you add another click handler to `.save`. So when you click on `.save`, all those handlers fire, and they each have a different saved value of `selected`.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: hey @Barmar thanks what i am trying to do is checking the $(this) value and displaying the alert box accordingly . as u have mentioned i have changed and trying it with .on() .

Answer (score 2):

As @Bramar already noted `.live()` is deprecated...use `.on()` or `.change()`.

That aside this is a really strange way to bind a click event. Every time you change your select value you also bind another handler to `.save` thats why you get both values in your log when the click event gets fired

Comment: Changing from .live to .on shouldn't make a difference. You still need to change the overall logic of your application.

Comment: i have a solution don't no whether its appropriate or not. the solution is as soon as i click and trigger the click event , i have bind the 2 handlers to it so i will unbind after the end of if statement. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my solution
<select class="sel"><option value="NULL">Select an Option</option></select>
<button class="save">Save</button>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".sel").change(function(e)
    {
        $( ".save" ).unbind();
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $(".save").click(function()
        {
            if(selected == 'NULL')
            {   
                alert("Select An Option");
                $( ".save" ).unbind();
            }
           });
    }); 
});
```